# Delete or shrink lobs file in a HSQLDB database

Tags: hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB 2.3.0. I have a database that the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE MEASUREMENT (ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, OBJ CLOB);
```

When I fill this table with test data, the LOBS file in my database grows:

```
ls -lath

-rw-rw-r-- 1 hsqldb hsqldb   35 May  6 16:37 msdb.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hsqldb hsqldb   85 May  6 16:37 msdb.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hsqldb hsqldb   16 May  6 16:37 msdb.lck
drwxrwxr-x 2 hsqldb hsqldb 4.0K May  6 16:37 msdb.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hsqldb hsqldb 1.6M May  6 16:37 msdb.script
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hsqldb hsqldb 625M May  6 16:35 msdb.lobs
```

After running the following command:

```
TRUNCATE SCHEMA public AND COMMIT;
CHECKPOINT DEFRAG;
SHUTDOWN COMPACT;
```

The lobs file is still the same size:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hsqldb hsqldb   84 May  6 16:44 msdb.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hsqldb hsqldb 1.6M May  6 16:44 msdb.script
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hsqldb hsqldb 625M May  6 16:35 msdb.lobs
```

What is the best way to truncate the schema and get all the disk space back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database engine is designed for continuous use in real applications. If you have an application that uses lobs and deletes some of them, the space will be reused for future lobs after each checkpoint.

In normal application use, the DELETE statement is used to delete rows. This statement deallocates the lob space for reuse after each checkpoint.

You can design your tests in a way that recreates the database, rather than reuse the old database after removing the data.

Comment: When I say test data, I meant "test data" to test if I can shrink the lobs file. Consider this use case: the application generates enough data to fill the storage medium. The application crashes because it is no longer possible to insert data into the database. I want to delete a portion of data in the database, so that operation can resume. How can I do this if I cannot shrink the LOBS file? Or should I just allocate X space for the LOBS file? Is this possible?

Comment: Updated. Use DELETE to remove the rows in batches and the lob space is released later.

Comment: But I don't see how this will shrink the LOB file later? So basically there is no way to shrink the LOB file once it has grown, even if space has been released in the LOB internally?

Comment: It will release the space internally and allow the engine to reuse it so the application can resume operation. It will shrink the .lob file if there is no LOB remaining.

Comment: I need something like the VACUUM feature in SQLite. In HSQLDB I have no way of preventing the LOB file from growing until it is big enough to crash the system. What would you suggest? Maybe a script to recreate the DB once the LOB is too big (because of internal free space)?

Comment: Please read the previous comments. CHECKPOINT will stop the file growing and the old released space is used after the checkpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I have an application with the same problem using hsqldb 2.3.3. The .lobs file seems to be growing indefinatly even after calling "checkpoint defrag". My scenario is that I'm inserting a 1000 blobs of 300 bytes each. I'm periodically deleting them all and inserting a 1000 new blobs about the same size. After a number of rounds of this my .lobs file is now 1,3GB in size but it is really just storing around 300kB of data. Inspite of calling checkpoint defrag the .lobs file just grows and grows. Is this behavoiur a bug?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior